# Adding custom fields to aspnetdb.mdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc

OK so I've created a new table within the existing aspnetdb.mdf database `aspnet_Groups`, and added and related a foreign key to the `aspnet_Users` table `GroupId`.

So users table now goes:

```
ApplicationId
UserId
UserName
LoweredUserName
MobileAlias
IsAnonymous
LastActivityDate
GroupId               //<--- Added by me, and related to aspnet_Groups table
```

Groups table only has `GroupId` and `GroupName` so it's pretty simple actually.

What I wanna know, is how do I save and get data for this field/table from within MVC application. Or does this have to be done another way?

Comment: Don't - if you need additional columns, create your own table that links to the existing `Users` table. Don't modify the existing Microsoft-provided tables - bad idea....

Comment: OK so I'm using EF Code first for my mvc app. How should I go about it? I just need to create those `Groups` and be able to filter `Users` by them.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I would not recommend intervining into aspnetdb working ... 
If you need to - create your own table and link it to aspnetdb.
More control, more customization, less bugs introduced to internal MS authentication...

Great posting about this [Storing data in a Custom table within ASPNETDB.mdf vs. storing information about a user in a profile](http://forums.asp.net/t/1403528.aspx/1)

But again, there's no right answer to your question - as long as it works and having good usability and readability - its fine.

If you can use Roles as your groups - this can do the trick, but if not, I'd define additional table, rather than intervining into prebuilt one. This is my opinion.

**Edit 2**

There are many ways you can work with aspnetdb. You can even embed it into your own database. Like this: [Configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Application Services to use SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx)

Answering your particular question: you can access aspentdb via authentication API:

```
string userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(emailToCheck);
if (userName != null)
```

or override membershipprovider, roleprovider and securityprovider or even access directly like described here

[Membership, Role, and Security](http://forums.asp.net/t/1736554.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm already using EF CodeFirst for the rest of my app data, and I'm familiar with it. I just need help with adding that group functionality to `Users` or at least an idea how to come about it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, that's a bit clearer. And no I can't use roles :( sadly. Occurred to me though. So a new table with `User Id` as foreign key? Kind of like what `aspnetdb` did with `Roles`? But again I'm not clear how to access that part directly... I think I'm confusing myself a lot here not sure why....

Comment: OK I'll look into it more, and get back at you. Thanks for providing info.